# I want to add all 28 possible combinations of domino to my Domino type (haskell)

Tags: haskell

module Dominoes where

```
type Domino = [(Int, Int)]

domino :: [(Int, Int)] -> Domino 
domino = [(x, y)| x <- [0..6], y <- [x..6]]
```

I have created my type Domino. now I have made a function domino to add all 28 combinations of dominoes to my Domino type but this does not seem to be working. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your type signature says that `domino` is a function that takes an argument, but your definition doesn't include any arguments. If you change the type signature accordingly by removing the argument, it works:

```
domino :: Domino
```

Also, in the future, you should include all error messages in your question. It makes it more likely the question will be answered quicker.

As a side-note, this probably isn't the type that you want for `Domino`. You probably want something more like:

```
type Domino = (Int, Int)
```

Your type signature for `domino` will then need to be changed appropriately (I would also suggest renaming `domino` to `dominoes`, especially in this case).

By the way, there also seems to be some confusion about `Domino`. `Domino` is a type synonym, which means it is exactly the same as the type it is defined as. It's just a name that can be more descriptive in type signatures, it serves no other purpose. So you aren't "adding" anything to the `Domino` type. If you want to do something like that, you will want to make it a `newtype` like this:

```
newtype Domino = MkDomino (Int, Int)
```

Then, you can write "smart constructors" which will only allow valid dominoes to be created.